# Equivalent to maven-install command in Grails 3

Tags: grails

I have begun the journey of migrating my Grails apps to version 3.

I have a number of plugins that I with Grails 2 have installed to the local maven repository with the [maven-install](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-release/docs/manual/ref/Command%20Line/maven-install.html) command available with the release plugin. They have then been easily accessible to my main project for import.

As far as I can see the release plugin does not exist for Grails 3. My question is, should I try to migrate the release plugin or is there some other, better way, in Grails 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
```

and the two `apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/...` lines from the `build.gradle` file that's created for you when you create a Grails 3 plugin you can run

```
./gradlew install
```

to do the same thing as the `maven-install` script.